# How to display random jokes from www.icndb.com in your terminal?

Tags: command-line, scripts, bashrc

I already know that you can get some nice quotes/jokes using the [fortune](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man6/fortune.6.html) program.

But I've found in this [urwird script](https://github.com/SeanZicari/pycon-curses/blob/master/quote-urwid-example.py) a new source of fun that I'd like to have when I open a new terminal.

This time the jokes come from http://www.icndb.com.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the icndb RESTful API: http://www.icndb.com/api/.

1. Install the `cowsay`, `recode` and `jshon` packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cowsay recode jshon
   ```
2. Then just add the following lines to your `.bashrc`:

   ```
   if [ "$PS1" ]; then
       wget "http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random" -qO- | jshon -e value -e joke -u |
       recode html | cowsay -f tux
   fi
   ```

   **Note**: checking if `$PS1` is set ensures that the jokes won't be displayed on non-interactive sessions.
3. Now when I open a `gnome-terminal` I get:

   [image]

Comment: If you're installing cowsay, you might as well install `jshon` too. It makes parsing the JSON a lot more concise (and probably faster): `wget "http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random" -qO- | jshon -e value -e joke -u`

Comment: @Oli Nice! Thanks, I also removed the need of python `HTMLParser().unescape()` with a call to `recode`.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll need that (recode) with JSON. And `jshon`'s -u should return a decoded string anyway.

Comment: @Oli: without the recode part I sometime get `&quot;` words after the jshon part.

Comment: Fair enough. That's icndb.com's fault more than JSON.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the default `~/.bashrc` already checks if it's an interactive shell (`[[ $- != *i* ]] && return`).

Comment: @nyuszika7h: You're right (I've just checked mine on 14.04). I don't know for older releases though.

Comment: No need for a backslash for line continuation after a pipe. The pipe causes the line to be continued by itself.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Good to know, thanks. Edited

Comment: If you add `?escape=javascript` to the end of the url (according to the api's webpage), then it won't use html entities (though you might need to `tr`im a few backslashes).

Comment: I use `wget "http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random" -qO- | jq -r ".value.joke"`