# Is there any way to execute a shell script whenever I open a terminal?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I want to display a message showing "welcome to terminal" whenever I open a terminal.
Any ideas?

Comment: See [How to display random jokes from www.icndb.com in your terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/q/527448/32239)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.bashrc` is your best friend for that approach.

Since `.bashrc` is linked to your account when you reached to your desktop after booting up.  When you open your terminal, the system will go through `.profile` then `.bashrc` for any specific instructions prior having the terminal ready for your use.

So, you can add `echo "Hello world, and you!"` at the last line of your `.bashrc` without editing anything in that script, and there it is...your terminal bows to you.

Comment: Note that `.bashrc` is also executed when you open another `bash` inside the existing terminal. So it isn't a 100% match of the specification.

Answer (score 3):

Open your terminal and paste as

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

write as

`echo " Ramana Reddy "`

at last line , save & close. Close your terminal and open it again.

NOTE: dont touch any other lines in .bashrc.

Comment: A better option would be `echo " Ramana Reddy " >> ~/.bashrc` ..no need to open the file..

Comment: He must know about .bashrc file

Comment: @RamanaReddy: Don't thank Raja!  ;-) If you like his answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the abysmally small number now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the number, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  That is a much better "thank you" to Raja than actually writing "thank you" ;-)